# NOP commerce, repeater-like behaviour

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I've also posted this in the Nop forum. I'm new to MVC and nop development. Here's what I want to do. I've got three new DB tables populated in the nop db.

I've a check on the TopicDetails.cshtml page to see if a certain topic id is being displayed, so I can check if a certain page is the one being shown.

If it is then I need to show a repeater of the data from one of those tables. Obviously even the term 'repeater' points to my web.forms history but I don't know the equivalent MVC term (for loop?).

So, I've created a new Model and a new controller but I've no idea how to query the db. I know NOP uses a code first approach but I've already created and populated the tables. So can someone help me populate some kind of result set of data by querying one of these new tables?

I'm looking at the TopicController but I'm confused by references to ModelCacheEventConsumer and ChildActionOnly etc. I just need to do a basic select on the DB.

If I'm shown once I should be ok to implement the others. So, how to query the DB and return a collection of type ?

Thanks. This is using version 2.65.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use constructor injection. Some possible pseudo code is given below but I stogly recommend you to study this link (http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/75/plugin-with-data-access.aspx) to understand the data access in nopcommerce, because the best way of accessing data in nopcommerce is to create a plugin.

```
private readonly IMyRepository _repository;

public MyController(IMyRepository repository)
{
    _repository = repository;
}

var data = (from data in _repository.Table
         select data);
```

Then in your view use loop to show the result.